# extract attribute values from xml with xsl-fo // is it possible?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Can I somehow extract/access the source, publication etc. inside the article tag? (with xsl-fo)

```
<telegraph_article>
    <article source="Telegraph Media Group" publication="The Daily Telegraph"
     creation_date="21_03_2016" section="FTR" wordcount="1203" storyname="23bkaa">
        <keyword1></keyword1>
        <text></text>
    </article>
</telegraph_article>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, MMoehrlein. Source would be xpath `telegraph_article/article/@source`, for the others just replace the `@source` with *`@attributename`* You use it in xslt by `<xsl:value-of select="telegraph_article/article/@source"/>` but it sounds like you are pretty new to all this

Comment: thank you very much ... well i started using xslt yesterday and can't really find a good source of learning so it is a lot trial and error :)

Comment: Good luck! there is some learning curve, try to understand as many samples as you can get hold of.